# Align and format one column

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following output of some script, which shows device, its uptime and firmware version

current output

```
device1  12:34:56 version  
device2  1:2:3    version  
...  
deviceN  H:MM:S   version
```

Expected output

```
device1  12:34:56 version  
device2  01:02:03 version  
...  
deviceN  HH:MM:SS version
```

As you can see Uptime column is not formatted properly (no leading zeroes in hours/minutes/seconds), and I need to format it nicely.
I tried to use split and sprintf but failed to get any good version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk '{split($2,a,":");$2=sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d",a[1],a[2],a[3])}1' file
device1 12:34:56 version
device2 01:02:03 version
```

It splits up the date field, and then using `%02d` to get the leading `0`

Comment: why it fails to add `0` before `12:34:56`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because that field already has 2 digits. `%02d` tells formatter to pad no more than 2 leading zeros if a digit is not 2 char long.